# What happened to icloud.com/activationlock page?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, activation-lock

I'm working in a pawnshop and when people attempt to sell or pawn an iDevice, I used to check its serial number or IMEI in icloud.com/activationlock. Now, without that tool, I'm concerned about activated phones that bypassed the activation lock with third party solutions.

Once a co-worked bought an iPhone 5 with iOS 7 apparently without iCloud account, when she tried to reset the phone, the activation lock asked for the owner's Apple ID, then I found the Apple's official tool to check phones IMEI and since, it has been very useful.

First, I want to know why Apple got rid of that page? And there is another alternative to check the activation lock status of an iDevice?

Answer (score 0):

Apple removed it.  It was being used as part of a hack (a very detailed hack) to allow people to get around Activation Lock.